# ¿Hacer una función Jquery como un ciclo con while?

Tags: javascript, jquery

quisiera hacer una función que se repita como un ciclo con while poniendo como condición que vaya del 1 al 4.
He formulado la función pero solo me ejecuta una sola función con el primer termino i = 1 y no con los siguiente 2, 3 y 4.

Alguien me podría ayudar en qué estoy fallando en el codigo Jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
i = 1;
var input = "#input-"+i;
var div = "#div-"+i;
while (i < 5) {
  $(input).change(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
      {
          $(div).show(); 
      } else 
      {
          $(div).hide();
      }
  });
 i++;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="input-1" checked=""> <span>input1</span> </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="input-2" checked=""> <span>input2</span> </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="input-3" checked=""> <span>input3</span> </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="input-4" checked=""> <span>input4</span> </label>
<br>
<div id="div-1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div-2">Div 2</div>
<div id="div-3">Div 3</div>
<div id="div-4">Div 4</div>
```

Comment: estas definiendo los var fuera del while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos problemas en el código (uno viene del otro):

1. Estás asignando el valor de las variables `input`  y `div` fuera del bucle, entonces no se actualizarán en cada pasada del bucle y siempre se asignará el controlador de evento a los mismos elementos.
2. Al mover las asignaciones a dentro del bucle, es mejor usar `let`, de lo contrario, cuando se lance el evento `change` va a usar el último valor que se le asigno (con `var` estarías definiéndolas en un contexto más amplio y se actualizarían con cada pasada del bucle).

Aquí puedes ver tu código con esos dos cambios y ya funciona:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
i = 1;

while (i < 5) {
    let input = "#input-"+i;
    let div = "#div-"+i;
  $(input).change(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
      {
          $(div).show(); 
      } else 
      {
          $(div).hide();
      }
  });
 i++;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="input-1" checked=""> <span>input1</span> </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="input-2" checked=""> <span>input2</span> </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="input-3" checked=""> <span>input3</span> </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="input-4" checked=""> <span>input4</span> </label>
<br>
<div id="div-1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div-2">Div 2</div>
<div id="div-3">Div 3</div>
<div id="div-4">Div 4</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sí había intentado lo mismo, poniendo el var dentro de bucle, pero no funcionaba, no sabía sobre `let`. Agradezco la respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

No necesitas un bucle.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){                
  $("input").change(function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
      {
          $("#div-"+id).show(); 
      } else 
      {
          $("#div-"+id).hide();
      }
  });     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="uno" checked=""> <span>input1</span> </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="dos" checked=""> <span>input2</span> </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="tres" checked=""> <span>input3</span> </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="cuatro" checked=""> <span>input4</span> </label>
<br>
<div id="div-uno">Div 1</div>
<div id="div-dos">Div 2</div>
<div id="div-tres">Div 3</div>
<div id="div-cuatro">Div 4</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no se me había ocurrido hacer eso. Muy agradecido.